# OCaml build error : type int instead of type unit

Tags: ocaml, ffi

I wanted to try out the OCaml FFI and bind some C functions like the
ncurses tutorial but I choose the ecore_evas (efl) instead:

here are the functions that I wanted to use:

```
void ecore_main_loop_quit(void)
void ecore_main_loop_begin(void)
int ecore_evas_init(void)
int ecore_evas_shutdown(void)
Ecore_Evas * ecore_evas_new(const char *, int, int, int, int, const char *)
ecore_evas_title_set(const Ecore_Evas *, const char *)
ecore_evas_show(ee)
ecore_evas_free(ee)
```

So I create the file ecore_evas.ml with this:

```
open Ctypes
open Foreign
let ecore_main_loop_begin = foreign "ecore_main_loop_begin" (void @->
returning void)
let ecore_main_loop_quit = foreign "ecore_main_loop_quit" (void @->
returning void)
let ecore_evas_init = foreign "ecore_evas_init" (void @-> returning int)
let ecore_evas_shutdown = foreign "ecore_evas_shutdown" (void @->
returning int)
type ecore_evas = unit ptr
let ecore_evas : ecore_evas typ = ptr void
let ecore_evas_new = foreign "ecore_evas_new" (string @-> int @-> int
@-> int @-> int @-> string @-> returning ecore_evas)
let ecore_evas_title_set = foreign "ecore_evas_title_set" (ecore_evas
@-> string @-> returning void)
let ecore_evas_show = foreign "ecore_evas_show" (ecore_evas @->
returning void)
let ecore_evas_free = foreign "ecore_evas_free" (ecore_evas @->
returning void)
```

then I created a mli file with those commands :

```
corebuild -pkg ctypes.foreign ecore_evas.inferred.mli
cp _build/ecore_evas.inferred.mli ./
```

the ecore_evas.inferred.mli

```
val ecore_main_loop_begin : unit -> unit
val ecore_main_loop_quit : unit -> unit
val ecore_evas_init : unit -> int
val ecore_evas_shutdown : unit -> int
type ecore_evas = unit Ctypes.ptr
val ecore_evas : ecore_evas Ctypes_static.typ
val ecore_evas_new : bytes -> int -> int -> int -> int -> bytes ->
ecore_evas
val ecore_evas_title_set : ecore_evas -> bytes -> unit
val ecore_evas_show : ecore_evas -> unit
val ecore_evas_free : ecore_evas -> unit
```

And I created a ecore_evas_window.ml with :

```
open Ecore_evas
let () =
ecore_main_loop_begin ();
ecore_evas_init ();
let ee = ecore_evas_new "" 50 50 300 300 "" in
ecore_evas_title_set ee "This is a test";
ecore_evas_show ee
```

Then I try to compile with

```
corebuild -pkg ctypes.foreign -lflags -cclib,-lecore_evas
ecore_evas_window.native
```

But I have this error message :

```
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g
-bin-annot -short-paths -thread -package ctypes.foreign -package core
-ppx 'ppx-jane -as-ppx' -o ecore_evas_window.cmo ecore_evas_window.ml
File "ecore_evas_window.ml", line 4, characters 2-21:
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
unit
Command exited with code 2.
Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
'_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in
subdirectories,
you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.

To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can
use the
following '_tags' file:

true: -traverse
<dir1> or <dir2>: traverse

Compilation unsuccessful after building 4 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

This message clearly show that the problem is related to the line
`ecore_evas_init ();` but I don't really see why it produces this error.

**edit** 
The original problem has been solved thanks to @hcarty but the full code was not working. If needed a working version can be found [here](https://github.com/cedlemo/ocaml_ffi_evas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ecore_evas_init` returns an `int`.  The `;` on that line implicitly says "the expression to the left returns `unit`".  Since `ecore_evas_init ()` returns an integer the types don't match.  You have a few simple options available:

1. Replace the existing line with:

   ```
   let _ = ecore_evas_init () in
   ```

   which will ignore the returned value.
2. Perform some check against the return value:

   ```
   assert (ecore_evas_init () = 0); (* Or whatever the "success" status is *)
   ```
3. Explicitly ignore the result:

   ```
   ignore(ecore_evas_init ());
   ```

   which is roughly equivalent to `let _ = ...`

In a full application you'd likely want more sophisticated error handling, but this should be enough to continue with this example application.

Comment: I have used the instruction `ignore`. Could you add it your answer. It would be helpfull for beginner like me.

Comment: Good suggestion - added